# RecyclerView height of item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have problem with measuring height of box.
I got two boxes (overlayed) :

[image]

One is displaying text etc and second box is when settings buttons will be clicked.

I got problem like a photo below

[image]

```
   holder.local_normal_box.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
    var height: Int = holder.local_normal_box.getMeasuredHeight()

    holder.local_settings_box.maxHeight = height
    holder.local_settings_box.minHeight=height
```

Blue overlay is settings box.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout) instead of LinearLayout. It is the layout recently recommended by Google